# JSON Decoder for Swift4

Tags: json, struct, decode, swift4, codable

Using Swift4, iOS11.1, Xcode9.1,

Trying to match the JSON-file in a codable struct for Swift4, I have the following issue:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
struct Station: Codable {

    let htmlAttributions: [String]
    let nextPageToken: String
    let status: String

    struct Result: Codable {
        let id: String

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case id
        }
    }

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case htmlAttributions = "html_attributions"
        case nextPageToken = "next_page_token"
        case status
        case result
    }
}
```

From what I understood, I have to place the Enum in order to allow for underline-keys that occur in the JSON-File. But after adding the Enum, the error message crops up. What is wrong with my Enum ? How is it placed correctly ?

Can you get me a go on the following JSON-File? How would I have to match it in a struct ? Any help appreciated !

Here is the JSON-File:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "F3ddaOzOcyo94AA2skDm",
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Strasse 1, 6003 Luzern, Switzerland",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.04951260000001,
               "lng" : 8.310404999999999
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 47.0508615802915,
                  "lng" : 8.311753980291503
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 47.0481636197085,
                  "lng" : 8.309056019708498
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "a3d600a6e78105b6ce2b5f5a3fac98ca1910a09b",
         "name" : "Luzern",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 4000,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113951418385089253589/photos\"\u003eAlex Marcu\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAYHK1VHDFlkbzXuMnF2MLEdew-36lgHC2lS1Cxg_DELgP-ckZH7G6aa-81LGDpR5rPZY1XMw64mytsjXIrdB5n3QQmXjGgelwZEbHaetT2jpy9SeaHDH3qUGGAUW-7BtZEhCxXy2dxGSv6A_g7fipsCr5GhRZlPuliykokXIkqfqIN_vMWzmYyA",
               "width" : 3000
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJqQIbhpj7j0cRjUguIM__gZw",
         "rating" : 4.4,
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAAzBZCshpypXcbMhrBQIdK2zISd3Q40QRSFO0KKhIrTejnGiZIoASuVqCVtmNBnFsodLWrYtOP-RmwCqDBDVbMheeCbFk7f0L8gwixLx_SGhYTDqPd6B2IwPWWXH5Pb6lxEhBoQtWj-kB-g1ZiOZ74hswNGhSd9Kf9Qj1P2_fdQCTO_VCoTU09JA",
         "types" : [
            "transit_station",
            "bus_station",
            "train_station",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ]
      },
      { ...more results... },
      { ...more results... }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Can anybody help me get a go on this ?

Comment: is `let result: Result` missing on purpose?

Comment: Oh - of course it was missing !! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

Is your `struct Station`  correctly like this?

```
struct Station: Codable {

    let htmlAttributions: [String]
    let nextPageToken: String
    let status: String
    let result: Result

    struct Result: Codable {
        let id: String

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case id
        }
    }

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case htmlAttributions = "html_attributions"
        case nextPageToken = "next_page_token"
        case status
        case result = "resulsts"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as holex was already pointing out to me (see his answer in comment above) - the result property was completely missing in my initial request. Simple solution :)

Comment: Ah, I overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

Complete this thing in the pattern I did and it will work fine. It works for me all the time!

```
struct Station: Codable {
    let next_page_token: String?
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Codable {
    let formatted_address: String?
    let geometry: Geometry
    let icon: String?
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
    let photos: [Photos]
}

struct Geometry: Codable {
    let location: Location
    let viewport: Viewport
}

struct Location: Codable {
    let lat: Float?
    let lng: Float?
}

struct Viewport: Codable {
    let northeast: Location
    let southwest: Location
}
```